beginner to ArcGIS mapping, help to map features and export the maps
I am looking for suggestions regarding how do I export a good map. I am looking for stepwise procedure to create a good map and export it so that I can paste it in my word document.
I have roadways shapefiles, I need to do the map. I am looking for stepwise process to do it, like starting from Map, adjusting coordinates, environment settings, project settings etc.
I am completely new to mapping in ArcGIS Pro.Looking for detailed and simple language for explanation.This is how I am expected to do
